# Add a new column with checkbox for a jTable created with vectors

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, vector, jtable

I have a JTable which is created using 2 vectors for header and data. The JTable is being created with the data. Now I want to add a new column at the end of the table to select some specific rows.

```
            //set header
        Vector header = new Vector();
        for(int i=1; i<=rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            header.addElement(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i));
        }
            header.addElement("Select");

        //set data
        Vector data = new Vector();
        while(rs.next()) {
            Vector row = new Vector();
            for(int i=1; i<=rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {                      
                row.addElement(rs.getObject(i));
            }
            row.addElement(false);
            data.addElement(row);
        }

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, header);
        tbl.setModel(dtm);
```

This is my code for creating the table. I have added a new column called Select. Just want to fill the column with checkboxes to select one or more rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to override [`getColumnClass(int col)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnClass(int)) method of `TableModel` like next:

```
    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(data, header){
        @Override
        public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
            if(col == CHECK_BOX_COLUMN_INDEX){
                return Boolean.class;
            }
            return super.getColumnClass(col);
        }
    };
```

where `CHECK_BOX_COLUMN_INDEX` - index of column with `JCheckBox`.

Also read [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and references!